# Runtime error on binomial model/node error on exponential model

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, binomial-distribution

I am trying to compare two versions of a binomal model on the number of successful putts. My data are:

```
x n y
2 1443 1346
3 694 577
4 455 337
5 353 208
6 272 149
7 256 136
8 240 111
9 217 69
10 200 67
11 237 75
12 202 52
13 192 46
14 174 54
15 167 28
16 201 27
17 195 31
18 191 33
19 147 20
20 152 24
```

where x = distance, n = number of tries, and y = number of successes. My binomial models are as follows:

```
# putt binomial model
model{ 
    for (i in 1:N){
            y[i] ~ dbin(n, theta[i])
            logit(theta[i]) <- alpha + beta*x[i]
    }

    alpha ~ dunif(-100,100)
    beta ~ dunif(-100,100)
}

# putt binomial model 2
model{ 
    for (i in 1:N){
            y[i] ~ dbin(n, theta[i])
            logit(theta[i]) <- alpha + beta*(x[i] - mean(x[]))
    }

    alpha ~ dunif(-100,100)
    beta ~ dunif(-100,100)
}
```

For both of these I get the same error:

```
Error in jags.model("puttbin2.model", putt.data, n.chains = 2) : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Failed check for discrete-valued parameters in distribution dbin
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Additionally, if I were to try and run an exponential model in this way:

```
# putt exponential model
model{ 
    for (i in 1:N){
            y[i] ~ dexp(lambda[i])
            lambda[i] <- alpha + beta*x[i]
    }

    alpha ~ dunif(-100,100)
    beta ~ dunif(-100,100)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in jags.model("puttexp.model", putt.data2, n.chains = 2) : 
  Error in node y[1]
Invalid parent values
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the unit for the putting distance?  Do you only count the first put on the green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JAGS/BUGS, the arguments of `dbin` should be in the order `p` then `n`. That is, `theta[i]` comes first, then `n[i]`. And notice you should have an index on `n[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response--in the end I figured it out, but initially was too impatient to have a think through.